# sharing variable of c# within many classes

Tags: c#, static

How should I design something like this? I have a projects that have many classes and I wish to have a counter (int type) that can be accessed by these classes. There should be only one instance of the variable and every time it will add one to the variable.

Comment: Perhaps consider looking up System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment.  It takes care of any threading issues that you might have.

Answer (score 4):

Use a static class with a public property would be the most simple solution. Depending on your situation, you need more advanced options (for multihreading, unittesting/mocking etc.)

You could use a singleton class to make testing a bit easier and locking in case of multithreading.

An example could be:

```
public class Counting
{
    private readonly Object _thisLock = new Object();
    private static readonly Lazy<Counting> InstanceField =
                            new Lazy<Counting>(() => new Counting());
    public static Counting Instance // Singleton
    {
        get
        {
            return InstanceField.Value;
        }
    }

    private int _counter;
    public int Counter
    {
        get
        {
            return _counter;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_thisLock) // Locking
            {
                _counter = value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected Counting()
    {
    }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
Counting.Instance.Counter ++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a utility  `static class` with all `static` memebers.

```
static class Utility
{
public static int Count = 123;//some value
/*some other variables*/
}

class MyClass
{
int mycount = Utility.Count;
}
```

**Note:** if you want to access your utility class outside the assembly you need to make your class as `public`